# BottomNavigationView not showing titles and icons

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

i am trying to use androidx BottomNavigationView in one activity with 3 fragment to navigate between those fragments , but the icons and titles are not showing .

[image]

i have tried many answers for the same questionand setting the  labelVisibilityMode to labled  but nothing worked

**activity layout**

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Sorting_activity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/triLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/stepsLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    </RelativeLayout>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/stepsLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttomLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/triLayout"
       >
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="682dp"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
            app:menu="@menu/buttom_navigation"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="682dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**menu**

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_theory"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_theory_24"
        android:title="@string/bottom_navigation_menu_theory" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_steps"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_sort_24"
        android:title="@string/bottom_navigation_menu_steps"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_code"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_code_24"
        android:title="@string/bottom_navigation_menu_code" />
</menu>
```

Comment: if you are using constraint layout then why relative?

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri without it the  BottomNavigationView moves to the top of the layout

Comment: andw why you need coordinate layout?

Comment: check my answer and tell me it works or not

Comment: use alignParentBottom to true in relative layout of bottomnavigation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to clean project and rebuild and
Try this way it works on mine

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/stepsLayout"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    >
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thank you , the code i posted worked after cleaning the project . but the bottomnavigationmenu is on top of the layout instead of buttom

Comment: set alignparentbottom to true in your relative layout of bottomnavigation

Answer (score 0):

If u can't see ur icons try add this:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:itemBackground="#ffffff"
    app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navegacion" />
```